# How to get eclipse JSP Expression Language validation to accept JSP 2.2 EL constructs?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, el

I have a page with the following JSP tag:

```
<c:set var="task" value="${report.taskMap['bin:'.concat(bin.id)]}" />
```

This works fine, but Eclipse complains about it being a syntax error, presumably because the '.concat(bin.id)' part is a JSP 2.2 extension not supported in older versions of JSP.  Is there any way of telling Eclipse to accept this syntax?  Or, alternatively, is there a way of telling Eclipse not to consider JSP validation errors as errors, and mark them as warnings instead?  I'd rather not turn off validation entirely — it is useful — but having the project marked as containing an error is causing all kinds of problems further down the line.

Comment: @exabrial No.  My assumption is that at least as far as eclipse 4.4.2 (the latest version I've tried) this simply hasn't been implemented.

Comment: That's been my findings as well. A [crappy] workaround is to change the warning/error levels in Eclipse.

Comment: Same for me in eclipse EE Mars - no solutions?

Comment: Can you put your pom.xml and associates taglibs

Comment: pom.xml is irrelevant - this is a problem on all projects. Only using JSTL, although even that isn't necessary to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a longstanding Eclipse validation bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352491

As of writing (6 years after the bug was raised), it still doesn't appear to have been properly fixed.

Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160577).